# "I would like to know what your name is" instead of "I would like to know what is your name"

Tags: grammar

Could anyone name the grammar rule that governs how "I would like to know what is your name." should be "I would like to know what your name is." If there isn't really a rule for that, could anyone explain why the verb and the noun should swap places for this type of sentence structure?

Comment: Colloquially they both seem fine and acceptable

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Really! I have always believed "I would like to know what is your name." is incorrect.

Comment: @FF etc The possibility of inserting punctuation isn't covered at the duplicate. Admittedly, OP here doesn't seem to have this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

'What is your name' is a question construction to be followed by a question mark and preceded by a comma.

I would like to know, what is your name?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Why would you precede this with a comma?

Comment: I edited to give an example.

Comment: The comma is because 'I would like to know' is not part of the question

Comment: You need to write more complete answers. You wrote this as if you were picking up half way through a conversation. In general, an answer this short will get moved into the low quality queue and will be voted on for deletion by the users of the site. Please make an effort to explain your answers more thoroughly.

Comment: I agree that this 'pseudo-quotative' structure is accepted nowadays, and that this type of example needs the comma (or colon / dash / ellipsis). Thus 'I'd just like to know ... what is the real reason you came?' But an answer on ELU needs supporting evidence.